# How to navigate through IE frames in internet explorer?

Tags: vba, frame

I'm trying to click through buttons on a webpage that appear to be in different frames which I know little about. I've written the following script:

```
 Sub Tabtest()
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.Top = 0
objIE.Left = 0
objIE.Width = 800
objIE.Height = 600
objIE.AddressBar = 1
objIE.StatusBar = 1
objIE.Toolbar = 1
objIE.Visible = True 'We will see the window navigation


objIE.navigate ("https://www.google.com/search?q=NYSE:WSO&tbm=fin#scso=uid_H2LSWorGEpD3gQaCt5uQBg_5:0,uid_bmLSWpGcLOLbgAbIzILQDw_5:0&wptab=OVERVIEW")
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until objIE.ReadyState = 4


    pageSource = objIE.Document.Body.OuterHtml



    objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("SVWlSe")(1).Click

   End Sub
```

The above clicks into the news tab. I now want to click the first news item (without just using the url).

How would I do this? I tried to get the element by class ID and then click but that doesn't work. e.g.:

```
objIE.Document.getElementById("Z25Gce").Click
```

The above returns the "object required" error. So I need to activate the frame with the news article in first.

Any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT:

There are 2 news tabs on the google page - the top list of tabs with "All, Finance, News" etc and the second list of tabs with "Overview, News, Compare" etc. I'm trying to click the "News" tab on the second list of tabs and then click the top news item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how robust this is.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Tabtest()

    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With objIE
        .Top = 0
        .Left = 0
        .Width = 800
        .Height = 600
        .AddressBar = 1
        .StatusBar = 1
        .Toolbar = 1
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.google.com/search?q=NYSE:WSO&tbm=fin#scso=uid_H2LSWorGEpD3gQaCt5uQBg_5:0,uid_bmLSWpGcLOLbgAbIzILQDw_5:0&wptab=OVERVIEW"

        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        .document.getElementsByClassName("SVWlSe")(1).Click
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        .document.getElementsByClassName("dbsr")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click   
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Although I should have specified, there are 2 news tabs on the google page - the top list of tabs with "All, Finance, News" etc and the second list of tabs with "Overview, News, Compare" etc. I'm trying to click the "News" tab on the second list of tabs and then click the top news item.

Comment: That didn't seem to do anything for me. There weren't any errors but it just stays on the initial page without clicking the second News tab or the subsequent first news article. Might be because the class names are different for us?

Comment: I only get one href which is probably what the problem is: I get this link:https://www.google.com/search?q=NYSE:WSO&tbm=nws&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5kMz73rzaAhUqDsAKHXE9D6QQ_AUICygC

Comment: Okay thanks. Unfortunately the code didn't do anything for me. BTW I'm already able to click "News" tab in the second row of tabs using "   objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("SVWlSe")(1).Click" which your code didn't seem to do. The only problem was then clicking the top news article but I'll have a look at the link you sent. Cheers

Comment: I had another go :-) I am not sure how robust this is though.

Comment: Haha thanks that worked perfectly. Funnily enough I found some solutions just at the same time:objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("div")(411).Click and objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("Z25Gce")(0).Click

Comment: I've already upvoted but still need points for it to show. Hopefully I'll get those points soon. Thanks!